# Datatables advanced filter menu like Excel or Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, excel, gridview, filter, datatables

I'm surprised not to find Excel like filtering in DataTables (since it is such a widely used and advanced plugin). Does this exist, or is there an easy way to implement it? Examples of advanced menu filter (like Excel) below. Thanks!

Kendo UI: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: The default filtering mechanism with the column menu is very similar to that second example you gave. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-menu alternatively you can also now use the new filter row feature and then pre-set this to a specific filter action eg contains, equals etc. Alternatively you can add your own custom filter for the column e.g. you want to filter based on a discreet list of items like Country, city etc.

Comment: This is an awesome example, but how can I implement this with DataTables?

Comment: So are you saying you want to bind the grid to a DataTable collection rather than an IEnumerable<T> Collection?

Comment: I'm saying that I want the filter icon in my table headers for more in depth filtering ability.

Comment: So are you not using a kendo grid for displaying this data? If you have a pro-license then you can just bind your datasource/ datatable to the grid and then implement the features. If you don't have this then a jsfiddle of what you are trying to achieve would be great.

Comment: I do not have a Kendo License (have in the past and it caused many issues). A large project I am working on is using DataTables, and on top of the column filtering I need a button for advanced filtering. http://jsfiddle.net/s827x/54/ (like Excel)

Comment: Ah ok. Now I understand. I haven't used that I am afraid but if you check the project site for it they have a list of plugins that can be used:http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/ (project site),  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/ (filter plugin) Otherwise you are going to have to build something yourself or look for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 6):

- **[Yet Another DataTables Column Filter (yadcf)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com) for jQuery DataTables**

  See [this example](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_Ajax_Multiple_1.10.html) for demonstration or the demo below.

  ```js
  $(document).ready( function () {
     
     var table = $('#example').DataTable();
     
     yadcf.init(table, [{
         column_number: 0
     }, {
         column_number: 1,
         filter_type: "range_number_slider"
     }, {
         column_number: 2,
         filter_type: "date"
     }, {
         column_number: 3,
         filter_type: "auto_complete",
         text_data_delimiter: ","
     }, {
         column_number: 4,
         column_data_type: "html",
         html_data_type: "text",
         filter_default_label: "Select tag"
     }]);
    
     // BOOTSTRAP: Tweaks
     $('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').addClass('input-group');
     $('.yadcf-filter, .yadcf-filter-date', this).addClass('form-control input-sm');
     $('.yadcf-filter-reset-button', this).addClass('btn btn-default btn-sm').wrap('<span class="input-group-btn"></span>');    
  });
  ```

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled::after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled::after {
     top: 8px;  
  }

  .yadcf-number-slider-filter-wrapper-inner {
     width:100px !important;  
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>jQuery DataTables</title>  

  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
  <link href="http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>
  </head>
    
  <body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-stripped table-bordered" id="example">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Some Data</th>
      <th>Numbers</th>
      <th>Dates</th>
      <th>Values</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 1</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>01/24/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,b_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 2</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>02/20/2014</td>
      <td>b_value,c_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag3</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 3</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>02/26/2014</td>
      <td>a_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag3</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 4</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>02/11/2014</td>
      <td>b_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 5</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>02/29/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,b_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 1</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>11/24/2014</td>
      <td>c_value,d_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 2</td>
      <td>222</td>
      <td>02/03/2014</td>
      <td>e_value,f_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag3</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag4</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag5</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 3</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>02/03/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,bb_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag5</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 4</td>
      <td>444</td>
      <td>03/24/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,f_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag4</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 5</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>03/22/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,c_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 1</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>02/20/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,b_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag3</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 2</td>
      <td>242</td>
      <td>02/04/2014</td>
      <td>d_value,aa_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 3</td>
      <td>703</td>
      <td>02/05/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,c_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 4</td>
      <td>604</td>
      <td>02/25/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,bb_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span> <span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 5</td>
      <td>550</td>
      <td>02/01/2014</td>
      <td>c_value,e_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag2</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 1</td>
      <td>901</td>
      <td>02/02/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,e_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag1</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Some Data 11</td>
      <td>911</td>
      <td>02/22/2014</td>
      <td>a_value,e_value</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Tag11</span></td>
     </tr>             
   </tbody>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```